# Replacing an element of an Array at a specific index

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two datasets. One is an array of strings, and the other one is an array of objects.

I am trying to...

1. Find the index of an item in an array
2. And then replace the item with another item in the array of that index

**But I can't get it to work on here** - https://jsfiddle.net/jt100/pbL2vyn4/7/. (**HELP**!)

```
  
  
 let weeklyDates = [
    "2020-12-21",
    "2020-12-22",
    "2020-12-23",
    "2020-12-24",
    "2020-12-25",
    "2020-12-26",
    "2020-12-27"
  ]
  
  let sitesID = ["1_STANNARY", "3_FOXCAFE"]


let hourlyWastes = [
{
  "hourlyWaste": [
    {
      "coverWaste": [
        10
      ],
      "Date": "2020-12-12",
      "dayOfYear": "347",
      "preparationWaste": [
        10
      ],
      "spoilageWaste": [
        10
      ]
    }
  ],
  "siteName": "1_STANNARY"
}, 
{
  "hourlyWaste": [
    {
      "coverWaste": [
                20
      ],
      "Date": "2020-12-23",
      "dayOfYear": "358",
      "preparationWaste": [
                20
      ],
      "spoilageWaste": [
        20
      ]
    }
  ],
  "siteName": "3_FOXCAFE"
}, 
]
  
 let hourlyWastesWeeklyDates = []
 
 let num;
 for (num = 0; num < weeklyDates.length; num++) {
   hourlyWastes.map((data) => {
    data.hourlyWaste.filter((item) =>{      
      if (item.Date == weeklyDates[num]) {
        let hourlyWastes = {
          siteId: data.siteName,
          date: item.Date,
          data: {
            "coverWaste": item.coverWaste,
            "preparationWaste": item.preparationWaste,
            "spoilageWaste": item.spoilageWaste
          }
        }
        hourlyWastesWeeklyDates.push(hourlyWastes)
      }
    })
   })
 };    



let sitesWeeklyDate = []
sitesID.map((data) => {
    let siteIdDate = {
    weeklyDates: weeklyDates,
    siteID: data
  }

  sitesWeeklyDate.push(siteIdDate)
})
 


hourlyWastesWeeklyDates.map((data) => {
  sitesWeeklyDate.filter((item, iNum) => {
    if (item.siteID === data.siteId && item.weeklyDates.includes(data.date)) {
    let indexNum = item.weeklyDates.indexOf(data.date)    
    sitesWeeklyDate[iNum].weeklyDates[indexNum] = data.data
    }
  })
})

console.log("sitesWeeklyDate",sitesWeeklyDate)
```

Could you please advise why it is not working?

I am getting the code return below in my console.log which is wrong because the date value "2020-12-12", from siteID "1_STANNARY", do not exists in the weeklyDates array therefore it should not assign an object to replace the date value "2020-12-23"

```
sitesWeeklyDate = [
 {
   siteID: "1_STANNARY", 
   weeklyDates: ["2020-12-21", "2020-12-22", {…}, "2020-12-24", "2020-12-25", "2020-12-26", "2020-12-27"]
 },
  {
   siteID: "3_FOXCAFE", 
   weeklyDates: ["2020-12-21", "2020-12-22", {…}, "2020-12-24", "2020-12-25", "2020-12-26", "2020-12-27"]
 }
```

the **correct** return from console.log should be

```
sitesWeeklyDate = [
 {
   siteID: "1_STANNARY", 
   weeklyDates: ["2020-12-21", "2020-12-22", "2020-12-23", "2020-12-24", "2020-12-25", "2020-12-26", "2020-12-27"]
 },
  {
   siteID: "3_FOXCAFE", 
   weeklyDates: ["2020-12-21", "2020-12-22", {…}, "2020-12-24", "2020-12-25", "2020-12-26", "2020-12-27"]
 }
```

**Thank you!**

Comment: Your fiddle has 1600 lines... I am not so sure anyone will want to look at those. Please provide a very simple case, where you provide the input (it should be clear which value all variables have that are used in your piece of code), and provide the expected output (in JavaScript notation), and what you get instead. Please don't add images of code. Code should be entered as text (and formatted), like the last block you have in your question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove a specific item from an array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array)

Comment: @trincot - sorry you are right no one is going to look at 1600 lines. I have reduce my code to 100 lines.   https://jsfiddle.net/jt100/pbL2vyn4/7/ Could you please tell me what i have done wrong here? Thanks

Comment: @SimonvanEndern sorry it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you pinpoint in your question originates here:

```
let sitesWeeklyDate = []
sitesID.map((data) => {
    let siteIdDate = {
        weeklyDates: weeklyDates,
        siteID: data
    }
    sitesWeeklyDate.push(siteIdDate)
})
```

In this loop you assign *one single* array to each `siteIdDate.weeklyDates` property. So you are pushing to `sitesWeeklyDate` objects which each refer the *same* array via their `weeklyDates` property. Later you do the following:

```
sitesWeeklyDate[iNum].weeklyDates[indexNum] = data.data
```

You mutate that *single* array, and so the effect will be equally visible in `sitesWeeklyDate[0]`, `sitesWeeklyDate[1]`, ...etc.

In short, you can solve this in the earlier quoted code, by making this change:

```
    let siteIdDate = {
        weeklyDates: [...weeklyDates], // <--- copy the array
        siteID: data
    }
```

I didn't look at any other logic in your code, so this might not prevent other problems from occurring, but it solves the issue at hand.

#### Some remarks

- Don't use `.map` when you don't use its return value. `.map` is intended to ...map, not just iterate. And actually, in the above example, you should use that power. You can then also use the arrow-function-expression syntax. And why not name the callback parameter `siteId` so you can use the shortcut property syntax. It could become:

  ```
  let sitesWeeklyDate = sitesID.map((siteID) => ({
      weeklyDates: [...weeklyDates],
      siteID
  }));
  ```
- Another concern is that you assign with `= data.data` in a loop. This again can cause a similar problem (if you later mutate that *single* object). You might need to change that to `= {...data.data}` to again take *a copy*. You need to be careful with assigning objects/arrays when you plan to later mutate them.

Answer (score 1):

It may be an array reference related issue.

Try the following:

```
sitesID.map((data) => {
    let siteIdDate = {
        weeklyDates: Array.from(weeklyDates), //<-- This.
        siteID: data
    }
    sitesWeeklyDate.push(siteIdDate)
})
```